# How to disable caching using XrmDataContext in Dynamics CRM 4.0?

Tags: caching, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

We are using the Advanced Developer Extension against Dynamics CRM 4.0. We have generated the entities and the Xrm context using CrmSvcUtil.

What we need to do is disable the built in caching that the context uses as it is returning incorrect results, but I've been unable to find out how to do this - any ideas ?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these links

- http://arens.ws/wordpress/?p=54
- http://community.adxstudio.com/Default.aspx?DN=d589dc6c-b2bf-4ae1-a8ca-06ac55f2a177&topic=40f3987f-9600-4a75-84f8-1dcffcfbd875&page=1
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398020.aspx

Comment: First 2 links no longer have any info

Answer (score 0):

Ok - found the answer at [this site](http://pogo69.wordpress.com/2010/10/29/to-cache-or-not-to-cache-crm-4-0-sdk-advanced-developer-extensions/)

```
CacheManager.GetBaseCache().Remove("adxdependency:crm:entity:[entityschemaname]");
```

Obviously replace [entityschemaname] with the schema name of the entity that you want to remove from the cache :-)